# How to filter out elements from an array that doesn’t match the query?

Tags: elasticsearch

stackoverflow won't let me write that much example code so I put it on gist.

So I have this [index](https://gist.github.com/Alino/4f7a80ee63012275605e#file-index)

with this [mapping](https://gist.github.com/Alino/4f7a80ee63012275605e#file-mapping)

here is a [sample document](https://gist.github.com/Alino/4f7a80ee63012275605e#file-sample-product) I insert into newly created mapping

---

this is my query

```
GET products/paramSuggestions/_search
{
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "paramName": {
                  "query": "col",
                  "operator": "and"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

this is the **unwanted** result I get from previous query

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.33217794,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "products",
            "_type": "paramSuggestions",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.33217794,
            "_source": {
               "productName": "iphone 6",
               "params": [
                  {
                     "paramName": "color",
                     "value": "white"
                  },
                  {
                     "paramName": "capacity",
                     "value": "32GB"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and finally the **wanted** result, how I want the query result to look like

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.33217794,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "products",
            "_type": "paramSuggestions",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.33217794,
            "_source": {
               "productName": "iphone 6",
               "params": [
                  {
                     "paramName": "color",
                     "value": "white"
                  },
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How should the query look like to achieve the wanted result with filtered array field which matches the query? In other words, **all other non-matching array items should not appear in the final result**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final result is the `_source` document that you indexed.  There is no feature that lets you *mask* field elements of your document out of the Elasticsearch response.

That said, depending on your goal, you can look into how [Highlighters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-highlighting.html) and [Suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-suggesters.html) identify result terms matching the query, or possibly, roll-your-own client-side masking using [info returned](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) from setting ["explain": true](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html) in your query.